# Get value out of Json return

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

My angularJs function returns response in Json, but I am not been able to get the 'model' part out from it.

Below is my code:

```
        this.search = function () {
    var response = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/TalentPool/Search'
    });

    return response;
}

this.search().then(function (response) {
    console.log('conscole: ' + response.data.model)
})

this.search().then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data.model)
})
```

And below is my mvc method:`

```
  List<CandidateSearchViewModel> output = CRBuilderObj.ContructResultsViewModel(data);
            CandidateSearch.model = output;
            CandidateSearch.baseCriteria = criteria;
            return Ok(CandidateSearch);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: where do you catch the promise

Comment: You can't return `response` like that. [Read the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: You might be correct, but I have seen that post and not been able to find the solution.

Comment: where you resolve promise ? where is `.then()`, See this [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmwdhm1r/)

Comment: My understanding is that its optional to have "promise"

Comment: `$http.get()` itself return the `promise`, you just need to resolve it by `.then()`, and by default, it handles JSON parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to access the response of the http request then you have to resolve the promise firs. then access the `model` property from the response

```
this.search = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/TalentPool/Search'
    });
}

//resolve the promise like this 

this.search().then(function(response){
     console.log(response.data.model)
})
```

Comment: I have updated my code but its still not working, Have I missed something here? "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: Still same error: angular.js:14339 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: need to return the http call from the function. u missed it\

Comment: (Code Updated) -> Have tried that as well  and getting error:  : [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/filter/notarray?p0=%7B%22baseCriteria%22%3A%7B%22EmpNo%22%3A10467%2C%22EmpTalentPools%22%

Comment: are using any filters